# Preloading content via rel=preload returns "headers do not match"

Tags: html, google-chrome, preload

I am trying to preload XML via:

```
<link rel="preload" href="http://xyz.local/at_de/cartware_3dpicture/index/profile/id/5637566859.xml/" as="fetch" type="application/xml"/>
```

I receive an error message:

> A preload for
>   'http://xyz.local/at_de/cartware_3dpicture/index/profile/id/5637566859.xml/'
>   is found, but is not used because the request headers do not match.

The file I am trying to preload is normally fetched via XHR:

[image]

The upper request header is from preload, the beneath request header is from the original XHR.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: It seems that rel=preload needs crossorigin="anonymous" to be set when using type="fetch" (which makes browser set request header Origin: domain.local. Problem with differing heads is now that its impossible for me to force Origin: domain.local to be set in my XHR request -> headers mismatch. I guess it would be solved if i would be able to forece "Origin" header information also the XHR is "same-origin".

Comment: Thanks Michael - `crossorigin="anonymous"` fixed this behavior for me.

Comment: It says many places crossorigin doesn't need the ="anonymous" but that is what solved this for me!

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem, even after adding the CORS headers. In my case, the `Accept` header was the crucial difference. Unless they're *exactly* identical, Chrome won't use the preload. Your `Accept` header has a couple extra parameters, which might be the problem.

Comment: How hard would it have been for them to add the headers to the error message! Ahhh!

Comment: I think I'm having this issue because between when the file is preloaded and when I access it the cookie value has changed. Which is not easy to fix.